# Implement GMM using tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, gmm

I am trying to implement Gaussian Mixture Model using Tensorflow.  Is there any guide or example on how to implement it?

I have tried to implement GMM from the tensorflow example [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.0/tensorflow/contrib/factorization/python/ops/gmm.py). But I think its buggy.

Comment: "I think its buggy" -> What is the issue?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt:- I am getting the following error `InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Input is not invertible.
  [[Node: MatrixInverse_2 = MatrixInverse[T=DT_FLOAT, adjoint=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](add_138)]]`

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt. Please find the a sample code [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7784#issuecomment-282081517)

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at [gmm_test](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/factorization/python/ops/gmm_test.py) of tensorflow. Simply use the gmm model is ok I think

In the official test cases you can find many details, which I think is better than document

But when I use it, there's a bug happened, I'm still investing it, hope you can help me

Comment: I've post a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43929589/use-official-gmm-module-as-gmm-test-but-a-bug-reported-operation-name-assert), If anyone solved the gmm module usage, please help me

Comment: There's a dead link.